# Set Background Color on <tr> in Loop

Tags: colors, background, row, tr

I want to set a **Same Background Color** on **Multiple tr's**. So that each **ROW** looks **separated** from the other one.

**Please take a look at this Image. I want to perform same:**

[image]

```
Check this DEMO:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RkVsp/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write css for your "table td" and "table" elements. collapsing borders will help you to fix this problem. i updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkVsp/50/).

**CSS:**

```
  table{
 background-color:gray;
  border-collapse:collapse;  
}

table td{
border-top:5px solid #fff;
border-bottom:5px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: There are some white gapes in row.

Comment: Great Work.Thats working fine. but if i have a row in same table for which i dont want any background colors, what to do in that case ? Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RkVsp/51/ I dont want Background color on Textarea

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/RkVsp/67/   
also thick my answer as solution if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS with a border-bottom attribute and be sure to set your cell spacing and padding to 0:

```
td { background-color: #FFC; border-bottom: 1px #FFF solid; }
```

Comment: Cellspacing is not a solution here. Because it will show multiple white borders in a row

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or Firefox and have firebug installed you should be able to right click to 'Inspect Element'.  This will show what style is being used.

Have a look at http://getfirebug.com/enable

Comment: What has your DEMO on jsfiddle got to do with firebug?